# Есть ли здесь парцелляция?

Tags: стилистика, литературоведение

> Дровосеки боялись в сумерки подходить к нему [к болоту] близко. Уверяли, что в летние ночи над водою прыгали и резвились огоньки...

Как можно определить парцелляцию? По каким признакам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Парцелляция** (намеренное разделение фразы на фрагменты) ― это экспрессивный синтаксис, его цель ― придать тексту образность, выразительность, эмоциональность. Это целая тема, одно из средств художественной выразительности в литературе.

**В данном случае парцелляция используется для перехода от описания к выводу.** Пауза нужна рассказчику, чтобы заинтересовать их каким-то фактом.

Но надо помнить, что неоправданная парцелляция является речевой ошибкой, к примеру: Собки бегут по полю. Гонят зайца.

Пример парцелляции: Однажды я проснулся среди ночи. Увидел грязную посуду на столе и опрокинутое кресло. С тоской подумал о вчерашнем (С. Довлатов)). http://www.durov.com/study/kurs4-1213.doc

Answer (score 2):

> Дровосеки боялись в сумерки подходить к нему [к болоту] близко.
>   Уверяли, что в летние ночи над водою прыгали и резвились огоньки...

Я думаю, Aer, что данный пример является парцелляцией. Подлежащее — дровосеки, однородные сказуемые — боялись подходить, уверяли. Ведь уверяли те же самые дровосеки, следовательно, второе предложение не будет ни неопределённо-личным, ни неполным (без сказуемого).

Поскольку парцелляция — это неоправданное деление предложения на смысловые отрезки, я определяю её так: если из двух или нескольких предложений можно (и хочется!) составить одно целое, это парцелляция.